# Barcode not scanned properly in InputBox of UserForm

Tags: excel, barcode, vba

I am creating an internal chemical inventory app using a  usb barcode scanner to read code 39 encoded item barcodes.

Note without any code the barcode insets the data correctly for a room number ie: RM240.

MY porgram has a UserFormScanScreen where there are InputBox commands that save the barcode to a variable called RoomCode which is then displayed in Cells(2,13) of the spreadsheet before advancing to the next input Box.

The scanner reads the correct data but  when it adds it to the cell it only adds  from the second character on ie.M240 and leaves the R displayed in the InputBox.

I am learning so dont know what im doing wrong thanks for the help. 
[screen display inputbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Jyb.png)

the code below is from the UserForm Code Screen

```
Private Sub TextBoxRoom_Change()

RoomCode = InputBox("Scan or type product barcode...", "Room Barcode") '

Cells(2, 13).Value = RoomCode ' Puts RMScan value into cell M2 
Cells(2, 13).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

TextBoxShelf.SetFocus 'advances to next TextBox

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note: but some people  have commented on other questions that using `.Value2` is usually more reliable than using `.Value`; because `.Value` sometimes gives unpredictable results.

Comment: Why are you using InputBox when you have a textbox set up to scan into?  The scan first enters "R", which triggers the inputbox, which receives the rest of the characters: the terminating "enter" added by the scanner then triggers the entry to the sheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams That is the actual answer to the question. Forget about the input box. And might as well abandon the use of  `Change` to `AfterUpdate` event especially for bar code scanners.

Answer (score 3):

In the Change event to need to look for "enter" at the end of the value, and act accordingly

Untested:

```
Private Sub TextBoxRoom_Change()

    RoomCode = TextBoxRoom.Text

    If right(RoomCode, 1) = chr(10) Then
        Cells(2, 13).Value = left(RoomCode, len(RoomCode)-1) '< strip the chr(10)
        Cells(2, 13).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        TextBoxShelf.SetFocus 'advances to next TextBox
    End if

End Sub
```

**Note:** for any textbox you want to be able to scan a barcode to, you need to set these properties:

- EnterKeyBehavior: True
- Multiline:        True

...in order to detect the terminating "enter" from the scanner